# Internet freezing up

Tags: internet, freeze, graphics

So I think I've been having driver issues, but it say the driver is updated and working fine. I have a Toshiba satellite A200-AH3. When I try to load pages, such as playhousedisney and others with 3d graphics, it will freeze up; it will work through but it takes time.  I've updated my java and other programs and still this problem persists. Can anyone help?

Comment: Operating system? Browser?

Comment: The internet freezes? Someone should warm it up...

Comment: Sorry i didnt provide enough info at first, but my OS in Vista, and im using internet explorer, i will try updating my browers maybe and try using firefox, thanks for the non-rude quick response dave.  Fot those who hate stupid questions, the only stupid question is the one not asked thanks bud.

Answer (score 1):

+1 with DaveParillo

Main question will be what OS and Browser are you using? If your video card says its good then you might want to try using a different browser. IE 8 or FireFox should do the trick. If your still having some issues try [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) to clean all your temp files and Registry errors.

For the mean time thats all I can say... Please provide more Info.

Comment: +1 for `provide more info`... I hate stupid questions without any clear documentation...